# Run Multiple AsyncTasks at the same time on Android

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, android-asynctask

I'm working on allowing my users to take a survey in my Android app. The survey is created in my rails server and the choices of the survey are posted back to the rails server.

So far things work great for single select questions - the users choice is stored and sent to the server. The problem is with multiple choice questions - I thought I could just loop through each checkbox and if that checkbox is selected send that choice to the server via the AsyncTask I'm using for the single choice questions. However, this seems to only execute the first time sending only the first choice.

Based on some other SO posts I've found it seems like Android has gone back and forth between allowing AsyncTasks to run parallel and not. Does anyone have a recommendation for how to handle this? I'd like to support back to API 10. Thanks in advance.

Here's how I'm calling the AsyncTask:

```
private void sendChoice() {
        mQuestionId = mQuestion.getId();
        if (mRadioGroupAnswers != null) {
            mAnswerId = mRadioGroupAnswers.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            new ChoicePosted().execute();
        }

        if (mAnswerHolder.getChildCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mAnswerHolder.getChildCount(); i++) {
                CheckBox selected = (CheckBox) mAnswerHolder.getChildAt(i);
                if (selected.isChecked()) {
                    mAnswerId = selected.getId();
                    new ChoicePosted().execute();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ChoicePosted extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Log.i(TAG, "ChoicePosted");

                boolean choicePosted = false;
                try {

                    choicePosted = new SurveyMe().postChoice(
                            "8d707d9fa2b279f381eb416f1be887c0", mQuestionId,
                            mAnswerId);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e(TAG, "Errors: " + e);

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "It worked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a better option to pass a list of answer values through rather than relying on the `AsyncTask` reading the `mAnswerId` variable, which could be changed by the `sendChoices()` method depending on order of execution.

Try creating a constructor for your `ChoicePosted AsyncTask` that takes a `List<String>` parameter, used to iterate through the answer Id's to send, so the iteration will be performed in the `AsyncTask` rather than spawning multiple `AsyncTasks` (Another option could be to send through a single `String` to the `AsyncTask`. As long as the `mAnswerId` doesn't remain global and editable by `sendChoices()` whilst the ChoicePosted AsyncTask is using it, you should be fine.

Example of adding a constructor to `ChoicePosted` that takes a `List` of `Strings` to send as answers:

```
private class ChoicePosted extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        List<String> mAnswersToPost;

        public ChoicePosted(List<String> strings){
               mAnswersToPost = strings;
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                for (String answer : mAnswersToPost){
                     new SurveyMe().postChoice(
                            "8d707d9fa2b279f381eb416f1be887c0", mQuestionId,
                            answer);
                }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I have left out a few things like your `onPostExecute` method and `try/catch` just to make the answer more easily readable, you'll obviously need to adapt this to your own specific use case.

So with this example, you would now create your `AsyncTask` like follows: (adapting your original code)

```
if (mAnswerHolder.getChildCount() > 0) {
     List<String> answerList = new ArrayList<String>();
     for (int i = 0; i < mAnswerHolder.getChildCount(); i++) {
         CheckBox selected = (CheckBox) mAnswerHolder.getChildAt(i);
         if (selected.isChecked()) {
             answerList.add(selected.getId());
         }
     }
     new ChoicePosted(answerList).execute();
}
```

So at no point is your `AsyncTask` and `sendChoices()` method using the same `mAnswerId` variable, instead holding onto their own copies that won't be inadvertently changed.

You should then be able to remove `mAnswerId` from your `Class` and you would of course need to factor in your first call to `new ChoicePosted()` (as I can see you call it twice).

This is of course the method where an `AsyncTask` is only run once, you can adapt to take a String (or use the `AsyncTask` parameters. Currently you have them all set to `Void`, but they can be used to pass parameters through directly to the `doInBackground` method and as return types).

For a more in-depth look at `AsyncTask`, you can read this Android Developer article [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'm totally gonna go this route!

Answer (score 1):

```
Below code will demonstrtate how to run multiple async task simultaneously in android


package com.vit.test.asynctask;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*
 * Disclaimer: this code is created as a quick prototype.
 * Please don't use it in production, because it neither handles 
 * device configuration changes nor the Activity lifecycle changes.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity   {

    // the number of tasks to be run in a batch
    private EditText numberOfTasksEditText;

    // the duration of payload job for a single task 
    private EditText singleTaskDurationEditText;

    // switches between 2 different modes (with/without parallel execution)
    private CheckBox enableParallelExecutionCheckbox;

    // each task increments this count as soon as it enters its doInBackground()
    // so this allows to track the order of tasks execution
    private AtomicInteger executedTasksCount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       

        numberOfTasksEditText           = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tasks_number);
        singleTaskDurationEditText      = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_payload_duration);
        enableParallelExecutionCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enable_parallel_execution);    
        }

    public void onStartTestClicked(View v)      {
        executedTasksCount = new AtomicInteger(0);       // reset this count

        final int numberOfTasks = getIntFromTextView(numberOfTasksEditText);
        final int taskDuration  = getIntFromTextView(singleTaskDurationEditText);

        log("number of tasks to run = " + numberOfTasks);
        log("task payload duration = " + taskDuration + " ms");

        final boolean useParallelExecution = enableParallelExecutionCheckbox.isChecked();        
        log("use parallel execution = " + useParallelExecution);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please watch the LogCat output", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity((Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP), toast.getXOffset(), toast.getYOffset());
        toast.show();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)    
        {  
            int taskId = i + 1;
            startTask(taskId, taskDuration, useParallelExecution);
        }
    }

    private void startTask(int taskId, int taskDuration, boolean useParallelExecution)   {      
        TestTask task = new TestTask(taskId, taskDuration);        
        if (useParallelExecution) {
            // this type of executor uses the following params:
            //
            // private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
            // private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
            // private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;
            //
            // private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
            //     private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);
            //
            //     public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            //         return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
            //     }
            // };
            //
            // private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
            //        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);

            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        } else {
            // this is the same as calling task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
            task.execute();
        }
    }

    private int getIntFromTextView(EditText v) {
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}
        return result;
    }

    private void log(String msg) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", msg);
    }

    private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> /* Params, Progress, Result */ {

        private final int id;
        private final int duration;

        TestTask(int id, int duration) {
            this.id       = id;
            this.duration = duration;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            int taskExecutionNumber = executedTasksCount.incrementAndGet();
            log("doInBackground: entered, taskExecutionNumber = " + taskExecutionNumber);
            SystemClock.sleep(duration); // emulates some job
            log("doInBackground: is about to finish, taskExecutionNumber = " + taskExecutionNumber);
            return null;

        }

        private void log(String msg) {
            Log.d("TestTask #" + id, msg);
        }
    }
}
//----place this layout code in xml
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number of tasks:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tasks_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="0"
            android:text="1"
            android:maxLength="4" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Task payload duration (ms):" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/task_payload_duration"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="0"
            android:text="1"
            android:maxLength="5" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/enable_parallel_execution"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Execute tasks in parallel" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:onClick="onStartTestClicked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Start Test" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```